# QList destructor behavior - Does call delete/free() on pointers in the list?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, destructor, qlist

I have a `class SomeObjectList : public QList<SomeObject*>`

I am creating pointers to `SomeObject` and sticking them in the list like so:

```
SomeObjectList MyClass::getSomeObjects()
{
    SomeObjectList list;

    for( int i=0; i<10; ++i )
    {
        list << new SomeObject();
    }

    return list;   // Crashes approximately here in QList::~QList
}
```

I'm getting a crash in the `QList` destructor, and it looks like free() may be being called.  I found the source code for the function (Qt 4.8.2) and it looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
Q_OUTOFLINE_TEMPLATE QList<T>::~QList()
{
    if (!d->ref.deref())
        free(d);
}
```

Does this mean that `free()` is being called on any pointers left in the list when the destructor is called?  I have used lists in other places without this problem.  Under what circumstances does the destructor call `free()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To elaborate: destroying a QList will destroy the elements of the list. If the elements are pointers, the pointers themselves are destroyed, not the pointees. You can use `qDeleteAll` to delete the *pointees*.

(That will use `operator delete`, which is the right choice if and only if you're using `operator new`; `malloc` will always require `free` and `operator new[]` will always require `operator delete[]`).

That having been said, returning a QList by value won't destroy it, as its refcount won't drop to 0. Getting a crash there means it's very likely that you have some memory corruption. Use valgrind or similar tools to debug that.

Comment: you could also define the list as `QList<QScopedPointer<someClass>>` and have not to deal with the deletion ;)

Comment: No, you can't. QScopedPointer is not copiable.